# why by default ,varibale is declared as static in c?

Tags: c, variables

```
    #include<stdio.h>
void func();

void func()
{
int y;
y=y+2;
printf("%d",y);
}

int main()
{
func();
func();
return 0;
}
```

Why is it printing 24 when func() is called second time,the variable y has to die? Why is it behaving like static variable even though it has not been declared?

Comment: Your code is generating undefined behaviour, the compiler should have warned you.

Answer (score 5):

It's **undefined behavior** because uninitialized local variable.

If you used automatic storage variable before a value has been assigned to it, that storage may hold whatever it held previously, and so the contents of the variable will be unpredictable.

C standard is 6.3.2.1 p2:

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that
>   could have been declared with the register storage class (never had
>   its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), the behavior is undefined.

So, Better if you initialize the variable just after creating, Like:

```
void func()
{
int y = 0;
       ^^^
y=y+2;
printf("%d",y);
}
```

Comment: But by default,it is initialized to zero all the time

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior because there is used the uninitialized variable `y` within the function `func`.

```
void func()
{
int y;
^^^^^^
y=y+2; // using an uninitialized variable
printf("%d",y);
}
```

As for the question then the function can use the same memory that was not overwritten by some other function. So the values stored in the memory can be the same between function calls.